# cement board around bath tub

Tags: bathroom

I am having my bathroom renovated professionally. Is it okay to have a crumbled edge in the cement board that causes a small gap where it meets the tub? Or does it need to be replaced?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.  And you don't have enough words to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

That gap should be filled with grout or mortar first before the waterproofing (probably RedGard or some other paint-on rubber thing) is installed.

Comment: The rest of the joints too, bedded with fiberglass tape